# Android how to use/show MediaController with SurfaceView and MediaPlayer for video?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have to use MediaPlayer to play a video, NOT a VideoView.
I have a SurfaceView in Xml Layout and on the Activity side a MediaPlayer and a MediaController.

I coudldn't find a way to use MediaController with SurfaceView and MediaPlayer. It is so easy with VideoView but cant figure out how to use with MediaPlayer.

I have found examples online but they are all about playing audio, not video.

This is surfaceCreated method where i create the MediaPlayer

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(mUrl));
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaController = new MediaController(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MediaPlayer Prepare: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and this MediaPlayer onPrepared method

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
        mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        startVideoPlayback();

        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);              

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
                mMediaController.show();
            }
        });    
    }
```

The code above doesn't show the MediaController on SurfaceView.
How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

for that you have to implement to activity

```
OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayerControl
```

check below working code

```
package com.example.demo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.MediaController.MediaPlayerControl;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayerControl{
    String url = "your video url";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer ;
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView ;
    SurfaceHolder holder ;
    private ConstantAnchorMediaController controller = null;
    ProgressBar progressBar1 ;
    MediaController mcontroller ;
    Handler handler ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        SurfaceView v = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface); 
        handler = new Handler();
        holder = v.getHolder(); 
        holder.addCallback(this);
        playVideo();

    }
    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            mcontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(url));
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         mcontroller.show();
         return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder); 
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mcontroller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mcontroller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.surface));
        mcontroller.setEnabled(true);

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mcontroller.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying(); 
    }

    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it displays application has stopped, I really need help with this please

Comment: It does not start the application, it only displays application has stopped
in the code side there are no errors displayed

Comment: @Lily Download working demo - http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2013/10/mediacontroller-with-surfaceview.html

Comment: I tried it and the same problem, the application does not start it just displays application has stopped. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This is the message that appears on the log cat ": E/AndroidRuntime(20047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mediaplayer_surf/com.example.mediaplayer_surf.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mediaplayer_surf.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.mediaplayer_surf-2.apk"

and then there are other messages which do not fit here

Comment: ClassNotFoundException error came ,may be you are declaring class with wrong package name

Comment: I mad sure of that more than once everything seems fine. Can you please provide me with the source code as an android application just to make sure the settings are right 
I tried downloading your source code but the zip file is not working probably 
thanks a lot for the help

Comment: parag here are screen shots of what I'm getting [first](http://s16.postimg.org/7dxl7x8h1/Capture1.png) and [second](http://s8.postimg.org/ytn97io79/Capture2.png)
As you can see the src folder is empty, please if it is not much trouble can you upload your code in bitbucket or github

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40064/discussion-between-parag-and-lily)