# Using surfaceView to stream videos

Tags: android, video-streaming, surfaceview

I tried running the code is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635013/android-how-to-use-show-mediacontroller-with-surfaceview-and-mediaplayer-for-vid/18135323#18135323)

but it is displaying application has stopped, I have been looking for an example to use surfaceView in live video streaming to android and Finally I found this but it is not working

I need live video streaming, since I'm streaming from an ip camera and I would like the streaming to be in real time

can someone tell me what the problem might be or help me with another example

Comment: why not using the VideoView? I am also about to write a video stream component. would like to know if VideoView would get me in trouble

Comment: @Warlock I tried using it and it works but it is too slow, I did some searching and found out some resources saying that surfaceview is more efficient 
I need live video streaming, since I'm streaming for an ip camera and I would like the streaming to be in real time

Comment: Thanks for the info +1 for question